# Multipart upload without image file in android

Tags: android, multipart

Ok this is my doing ,Currently I'm working on class file ,the situation is explained below,

1) I usually collect input from 6 or 7 EditText

2)There will be three buttons to choose three files ,it is not compulsory to choose all 3 files ,he may choose 1,2 or 3 ,it is also not compulsory to choose even 1 image..

the problem is here ,,

what i did was using for loop to iterate through images ,and for each loop i upload image along with collected inputs from editext

as i said earlier it is not compulsory to upload image,,how can i use same code to send inputs from edittext without images,,,,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Suppose if u are using Multipart and trying to use the same service for Sending content with and without Image it is not possible to send ,,Because Multipart cannot accept null values .So,better option is to use two seperate services on for sending image using multipart and other without multipart,,